# How to filter providers in easy!appointments

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am trying to integrate the following code:

```
    <html> 
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<body> 
Please enter your Suburb:
<input type="text" name="location_input" id="location_input"> 
Tutor:<select name="locations" id="locations"> 
</select> 

<script> 
    $("#location_input").keyup(function(){ 
        const location = $("#location_input").val(); 
        $("#locations").html(''); //reset dropdown 
        // do ajax call to get locations 
        $.ajax({ 
            url: 'search.php', //replace this with your route of the search function 
            data: {location}, //pass location as body data             
            success: function(data) { 
                let res = JSON.parse(data);
                res.forEach(function(el) { //loop over the json response 
                let option = `<option id=${el.id} value=${el.name}>${el.name}</option>` 
                $("#locations").append(option); //append locations to select dropdown 
                }); 
            }, 
            error: function(err) { //error functions 
                console.log(err); 
                alert("Error") 
            } 
        }); 
    }); 
</script> 

</body> 
</html>
```

Search.php:

```
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $db_name);

// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

// echo "Connected successfully";

// print_r($_GET["location"]);
$location = $_GET["location"];

$result = $conn->query("select id, name, Location_tags from tutor_location where Location_tags LIKE '%". $location ."%'");


$locations = [];

while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $locations[] = $row;            
    // echo $row["Name"];
}

echo json_encode($locations);


?>
```

into my easy!appointments module for when a user selects a provider. I want the user to enter in his suburb and it must show providers based on that location. In the database, I have a field called `location_tags` where the provider specifies which suburbs he would like to go to.

The code where I am trying to integrate is in here:

```
 <div class="form-group" id="selectprovider">
                            <label for="select-provider">
                                <strong><?= lang('select_provider') ?></strong>
                            </label>

                            <select id="select-provider" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 form-control"></select>
                        </div>
```

This is in the Easy!appointments module made by Alex Tselegidis
How do I integrate this? 
[Link to Easy!appointments](https://easyappointments.org/)

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @vincent-d the integration does not want to work

Comment: ajax operation was not performing ?

Comment: it was not showing any output

Comment: @MohammedIsmail Put a clear question or better, an issue in your post in my opinion